# Woman is sucked into a book with a medieval world at war

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, medieval

I started to read this book a while ago and did not finish it. I would like to read it again.

A girl was walking down the stairs while reading a book when she fell and landed on top of the book and she was sucked in. She was transported into a medieval world where there is a war. She realizes she was in her book. She join with the characters in the book to fight the war. It's in English, I read it somewhere in 2009-2011, and if I'm not mistaken the book had a green cover with a picture of a castle.

Comment: Do you remember approximately what year you read this and in what country? And did she fall down as in she tripped, or did she fall into something like a hole or a book explicitly? Did the medieval troops speak English? French? German?

Comment: I think i read it somewhere in 2009-2011

Comment: I'll admit that's not what I would have expected for "a long time ago" :-P

Comment: I remember she was walking  down the stair while reading when she fell and land on top of the book snd she was sucked in.. its in English and if im not mistaken the book has green cover with picture of castle

Comment: So... if she was "sucked into a book", it's not really time travel...

Comment: Related, but not a direct help that I could tell: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PortalBook

Comment: Do you remember any other characters or how she got out of the book?

Comment: One of the character is a prince and she fell in love with him. So far the events she encountered is the same as the the ones in the book so she can help with the war. But has not finish reading the book

Comment: Possible duplicate of unanswered https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171851/looking-for-book-about-a-girl-who-traveled-inside-a-storybook?rq=1. All credit to 'Related' column for suggesting it.