# Looking for book about a girl who traveled inside a storybook

Tags: story-identification, books

I would like to finish reading this book

**Year:** around 2009 - 2011

**Type:** ebook/ YA

**Summary:** A girl was reading a book while running down the stairs. She was late for archery practice. She fell down and got sucked inside the book she was reading. She met the characters in the book. There was a prince, castle, wars... That's all I can remember.

Comment: Vaguely remember something like that from when I was a kid within the timeframe mentioned. Could just be a fairly well known trope though